# script that checks for specific phrases in an https response for a list of urls and returns a not working status

Tags: javascript, http, google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

I have a list of embed urls, and I want to check the ones that are not working.
The problem is the one that is not working; it is not a broken link; it just deleted from the website and still displays a webpage that tells you that the file is deleted.

The script is searching for specific phrases that are stored in an array in an https response from a list of urls and returning a not working status; the default status is Working.

The script is working fine, but the problem is that the urls have different websites, and some of them return a a working statuss even if the phrases are displayed in the webpage.

the function take a cell containing the URL as a parameter and return the value

```
function CheckVideoStatus(urlCell) {
  var status = "Working"; // Default status
  
  // Phrases and patterns to consider as "Not Working" status
  var notWorkingPhrases = [
    "File is no longer available as it expired or has been deleted.",
    "has been deleted",
    "File not found",
    "The file expired",
    "This file is not available any more",
    "File no longer accessible",
    "The file you are trying to download is no longer available",
    "File Not Found",
    "any inconvenience",
    "The file was deleted by its owner",
    "500 Internal Server Error",
    "Unfortunately, the file you want is not available",
    "video you are looking for is not found",
    "Not Found",
    "file/folder",
    "claim by 4shared Support Team",
    "of a claim",
    "violation of our",
    "We're sorry.",
    "You need access",
    "Update your browser",
    "File is no longer available",
    "The video has been blocked",
    "This file is not available anymore",
    "File no longer accessible",
    "access",
    "Update your browser",
    "available",
    "blocked",
    "not available anymore",
    "accessible",
    "Not Found",
    "no longer",
    "longer",
  ];

  var url = urlCell; // Get the URL from the cell

  if (url !== "") {
    var response = getHTTPResponse(url);

    // Check for the specified phrases and patterns in the HTML response
    var isNotWorking = false; // Initialize a flag

    for (var k = 0; k < notWorkingPhrases.length; k++) {
      if (response.toLowerCase().includes(notWorkingPhrases[k].toLowerCase())) {
        isNotWorking = true; // Set the flag to true if any phrase is found
        break; // No need to check further phrases once "Not Working" is determined
      }
    }

    if (isNotWorking) {
      status = "Not Working";
    }
  }

  return status;
}

function getHTTPResponse(url) {
  var response = "";
  try {
    response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  } catch (e) {
    // Handle any errors if necessary
  }
  return response;
}
```

For example, if I tried the function on this, it would return a working status even if one of the phrases were displayed on the webpage.
https://mega.nz/embed/8UwSlQ7J!qWLIL_H8I9KLByJkBTO0747Zky0B0F1YqGFijkObVsg

Comment: `console.log(response)` to figure out the phrase returned to Google.

Comment: The output is the same for deleted files and non-delete files, and I didn't find the phrases in the code; that's weird. I noticed the response for this website is different from the code if you inspect the webpage.

Comment: As I see it, in some cases like the one you show as an example, you need to "navigate" the site to "get" to the information you need.
You can look into solutions like Selenuim or Puppeteer, but I'm not sure if they can be integrated into GAS. It is very possible that you need to run the process on another platform and then query it from GAS.